# How do I make a rope from point A to B in Box2D?

Tags: 2d, box2d

I need to make a rope (preferably not elastic) from one point to the next in Box2D. If it helps, I'm trying to develop one of those 2D Spiderman games, like this: http://www.gamesbutler.com/game/4327/Hanger/

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Box2D manual for `b2EdgeChainDef`. Simply restrict the parameters so that there is no elasticity per edge/joint.