# How to create an extensible rope in Box2D?

Tags: box2d

Let's say I'm trying to create a ninja lowering himself down a rope, or pulling himself back up, all whilst he might be swinging from side to side or hit by objects. Basically like http://ninja.frozenfractal.com/ but with Box2D instead of hacky JavaScript.

Ideally I would like to use a rope joint in Box2D that allows me to change the length after construction. The standard Box2D `RopeJoint` doesn't offer that functionality.

I've considered a `PulleyJoint`, connecting the other end of the "pulley" to an invisible kinematic body that I can control to change the length, but `PulleyJoint` is more like a rod than a rope: it constrains maximum length, but unlike `RopeJoint` it constrains the minimum as well.

Re-creating a `RopeJoint` every frame using a new length is rather inefficient, and I'm not even sure it would work properly in the simulation.

I could create a "chain" of bodies connected by `RotationJoint`s but that is also less efficient, and less robust. I also wouldn't be able to change the length arbitrarily, but only by adding and removing a whole number of links, and it's not obvious how I would connect the remainder without violating existing joints.

This sounds like something that should be straightforward to do. Am I overlooking something?

**Update**: I don't care whether the rope is "deformable", i.e. whether it actually behaves like a rope, or whether it collides with other geometry. Just a straight rope will do. I can do graphical gimmicks while rendering; they don't need to exist inside the physics engine. I just want something a `RopeJoint` whose length I can change at will.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a rope from point A to B in Box2D?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/how-do-i-make-a-rope-from-point-a-to-b-in-box2d)

Comment: I'm not so sure that rope in the demo you showed is a physics object. It looked like it wasn't colliding with the character or the cave walls. Could just use a spline.

Comment: I use Box2D quite a bit and have no idea how to achieve this and doubt that its possible.

Comment: @Byte56: Not a dupe. The "extensible" bit is what is different. Also, I don't care if my rope is straight; I can add some fancy animation on top of that.

Comment: @Byte56: I wrote the rope in the demo -- it is true that it doesn't collide with anything. I'm using a spline to render it nicely but internally it's just two points and a maximum distance. And I can change the length, which is what Box2D doesn't seem to let me do...

Comment: Do you want to make a "deformable" rope? I believe its not possible in box2d, as it's a [rigid body physics engine](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html); check [soft body dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics), I would sugest the [Bullet library](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/).

Comment: If you really want a "deformable" rope, I'll put my previous comment on an answer.

Comment: My "chain" would approximate a deformable rope, but this is not what I'm looking for -- see update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I naively assumed that [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) wrapped all of Box2D, so this would be purely a Box2D problem.

It turns out that vanilla Box2D, at least in trunk, has a function called `b2RopeJoint::SetMaxLength`. I've added it and got a pull request merged within minutes. It is now available (and working) in LibGDX nightlies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "deformable" rope, that isn't possible in box2d, as box2d is a [rigid body physics engine](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html); check [soft body dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics), I would sugest the [Bullet library](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/).

A "simpler" solution using box2d would be to "emulate" the variation of length by hiding some of the rope (with fixed length) outside the visible world / not drawing some of the rope.

[image: schematics]

This would work like pulling the top extremity (b) of the rope (c) up/downwards. I would add some static objects (a) so that the ninja doesn't escape the visible world for too long...

Comment: Sorry, it seems my description still isn't clear. I don't care whether the rope is deformable; softbodies are overkill especially since I'm targeting a mobile platform.

Comment: Your other idea is interesting, but I don't quite see how I would set this up using rigid bodies and joints. I could use a stick to simulate the rope, but it would constrain the distance between the ninja and attachment point to be constant, whereas I just want to constrain it to a maximum.

Comment: I added the "deformable" only for completeness (you said you "didn't care", not that "didn't want" :P)